# set cron job for a php file

Tags: php, cron

I am new to cron jobs. I have linux shared hosting at go daddy with a cron job manager. Been playing with it since 2 days but no success. Now I decided to create a crontab. I have a php file which needs to be run after every 3 hrs. For that I made a line:

`15 */3 * * *  /web/cgi-bin/php5 /home/content/613/html/content/runningfile.php`

But I don't know how to start with it. Where to put this line into and that file which format and where to add etc. and thereafter.

Can anyone guide please?

Comment: make sure your shared hosting allow php cli, and the path of php executable is correct.

Comment: how can I get to know that?

Comment: I have php cgi installed.

Comment: ask your hosting provider how to setup cron. every provider has different rules about this.

Answer (score 0):

To edit your user's cron table, type the following:

```
crontab -e
```

You should then be able to paste that line into the file and save it.

Comment: Thanks, Phylogenesis for replying. I am standing with just one thing now, wanted to run a phpfile every 3 hrs. Where to start from. I ave read questions here, but haven't found detailed method.

Comment: Ok, I tried command-line using Putty SSH. Writing crontab -e gives:
/usr/bin/crontab: Permission denied

Comment: @user2299278 that means your user account is not in the cron group. since you are in shared hosting, you better consult the hosting provider rather than ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cURL to execute a php script in the cron manager:

0 */3 * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed /home/content/613/html/content/runningfile.php

Comment: but my cron manager already has scheduling options how can I give these times with their inbuilt time dropdown menu?